# Get data from database pagination without refresh (symfony2)

Tags: ajax, symfony

I am new to [symfony2](http://symfony.com/) and this is my first question(please forgive me if something looks funny).

I've used some other 3rd party bundles before, but i need a way，which can implement pagination without refresh.

So, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: please be more specific? what you have tried, where problem are you facing, expected result and error messages (if any)

Comment: hum! i know how to do that without any framework, i am new to symfony2,and i don't kown how to configure the route.I will post some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pagerfanta](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta) for pagination and use ajax call to update your view.